# Issues creating a box using CSS

Tags: css

I want to create a box shape and I am having trouble.
I want the box to have a background color, and then different color inside the box.
The box will then have a list of items using ul and li, and each list item will have a background of white, and the list item's background color is too stretch the entire distance of the inner box.
Also, the list items should have a 1 px spacing between each one, so that the background color of the inside box color is visible.

Here is a rough sketch of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this pretty cleanly with this css:

```
.box {
        width: 100px;
        border: solid #884400;
        border-width: 8px 3px 8px 3px;
        background-color: #ccaa77;
}

.box ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        padding-top: 50px; /* presuming the non-list header space at the top of
                              your box is desirable */
}

.box ul li {
        margin: 0px 2px 2px 2px; /* reduce to 1px if you find the separation
                                    sufficiently visible */
        background-color: #ffffff;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 2px;
}
```

and this html:

```
<div class="box">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0b7w65qv/)

Comment: that looks great, except for some reason the width isn't 100% of that container, actually it is very narror for some reason, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

So if you have source:

```
<div class="panel">
  <div>Some other stuff</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can use CSS:

```
div.panel { background-color: #A74; border: solid 0.5em #520; width: 10em; 
            border-width: 0.75em 0.25em 0.75em 0.25em; }
div.panel div { padding: 2px; height: 4em; }
div.panel ul li { display: block; background-color: white; 
                      margin: 2px; padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px; }
div.panel ul { margin: 0; padding-left: 0; }
```

To get the CSS to work properly (particularly on Internet Explorer), make sure you have an appropriate DOCTYPE definition in your document.  See [w3c recommended doctypes](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) for a list.

Comment: Why the child selectors?  I'm not aware of a doctype that will enable child selectors (>) to work in IE6...

Comment: OK, well I removed them since they were surplus to requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Examples of margins, padding, and borders</TITLE>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
      UL { 
        background: yellow; 
        margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
        padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
                                     /* No borders set */
      }
      LI { 
        color: white;                /* text color is white */ 
        background: blue;            /* Content, padding will be blue */
        margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
        padding: 12px 0px 12px 12px; /* Note 0px padding right */
        list-style: none             /* no glyphs before a list item */
                                     /* No borders set */
      }
      LI.withborder {
        border-style: dashed;
        border-width: medium;        /* sets border width on all sides */
        border-color: lime;
      }
    </STYLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <UL>
      <LI>First element of list
      <LI class="withborder">Second element of list is
           a bit longer to illustrate wrapping.
    </UL>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those two will help:

- [Listutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/)
- [CssPlay Menus](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/)

Answer (score 0):

### Html:

```
<div id="content">
        <a><div class="title">Title</div>Text</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Text</li>
            <li>More Text...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

### CSS:

```
#content{
            text-align:left;
            width:200px;
            background:#e0c784;
            border-top:solid 10px #7f4200;
            border-bottom:solid 10px #7f4200;
            border-right:solid 5px #7f4200;
            border-left:solid 5px #7f4200;
        }
        #content a{
            margin-left:20px;
        }

        #content ul{
            list-style-type:none;
            margin-bottom:0px;
        }
        #content ul li{
            padding-left:20px;
            margin:0px 0px 1px -40px;
            text-align:left;
            width:180px;
            list-style-type:none;
            background-color:white;
        }
        #content .title{
            text-align:center;
            font-weight:bolder;
            text-align:center;
            font-size:20px;
            border-bottom:solid 2px #ffcc99;
            background:#996633;
            color:#ffffff;
            margin-bottom:20px;
        }
```

Hope this helps.... I also added a title to it, if you dont like it just delete it...